# Angular2 stateless components style

Tags: angular, shadow-dom, stateless

## What am I doing:

I'm coding my new app using stateless components with Angular 2.

## What I want to do

I want create generic component `list` which contain repeated widgets.
There can be a few types of them:

- Simple item
- Habit widget item
- Another widget item

So I can create list of habits, list of users etc. and it's not always a table. It can be list of any widget.

## What am I doing to reach it.

In my statefull view html I put `list` component and using Web Component's transclusion set what type of widget should be repeated inside.

#### statefull view

```
<list [items]="habits">
  <div elements>
    <list-item *ngFor="#item of habits"
               [item]="item"></list-item>
  </div>
</list>
```

#### list component

```
<ng-content select="[elements]"></ng-content>
```

## What's the problem with my solution

- I need to pass habits object to 2 different places what will cause difficult to find problem if I don't pass the same.
- Need to handle ngFor from the app view. So I'm doing something what *list component* should handle itself.

## Conclusion

Is there any better solution how I can put `list` component inside my statefull view HTML and decide there what type of widgets it should contain?

Of course I will create all this widgets.

Comment: How is "stateless" and "shadow DOM" related to this all? I guess you relate to `<content>` from Polymer which allows to project children into the view of another component - is that the case? In Angular2 this is `<ng-content>`. I looked a bit into a similar list implementation. I think it's possible but not too easy. You could just use `*ngFor` and just use a class that does the data manipulation instead of a component. Otherwise I think a starting point is the `TemplateRef` class and the `NgFor` implementation.

Comment: Shadow DOM is used by Angular2 like a new alternative to translusion.
These components what I'm creating are stateless. They should be stupid and generic.

Comment: Ok, then I assumed right. Shadow DOM itself isn't really about transclusion but the `<content>` or `<ng-content>` tag does it. Angular2 defaults to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` which is **not** shadow DOM. To enable shadow DOM you need to set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` on each component but that's not really related to your question. Transclusion works mostly the same with or without shadow DOM in Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

I find it strange to create **dom elements** in one component and then simply reproduce them in another - you should be passing your **model** down the component tree (ideally smaller and smaller parts of the model) using attributes. In your particular example I don't see two genuinely different parts of the DOM, so I would not use nested components at all.